# How to check if a public key matches a given private key?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I would like to use Ruby and its OpenSSL module to check whether a public key matches a given private key. Basically a user enters both a private key and a public key and I want to make sure that they match (they belong to the same key pair).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @mudasobwa I would expect an OpenSSL method like `public_key.matches?(private_key)` but I can't find anything like that. So I have no idea how to check that they match

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is to sign a message with the private key and then try to verify the message with the public key:

```
public_key.verify(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new, private_key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new, 'message'), 'message')
```